# wsdl not showing XML-WCF

Tags: wcf, wsdl

When calling service url https://example.com/TestService.svc I am getting the below 2 URLs but when I am trying to click on WSDL then it is not working.

WSDL URLs

http://example.com/TestService.svc?wsdl -- NOT WORKING

http://example.com/TestService.svc?singleWsdl -- NOT WORKING

Manually change http to https

https://example.com/TestService.svc?wsdl -- WORKING

https://example.com/TestService.svc?singleWsdl -- WORKING

Client Config

```
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</client>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <clear/>
    <behavior>          
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>          
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
```

Main Service Config

```
<system.serviceModel>    
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <clear />
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0">
  <serviceActivations>
    <clear />        
    <add factory="DataServicesHost.UnityServiceHostFactory" relativeAddress="TestService.svc" service="TestService.Service" />
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Service Consuming

```
var customHeader = new MessageHeader<Security>(security);
            var tempHeader = customHeader.GetUntypedHeader("Security", "http://tempuri.org/");

            var client = new ServiceClient();

            using (var scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
            {
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(tempHeader);
                objDataRequest = client.DataRequest("test");

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the above configuration, we can infer that it belongs to the client-side. However, the WSDL feature of the WCF service is set up on the server-side. It is controlled by the ServiceMetadata section.

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
```

Therefore, if we want to have the HTTP protocol of WSDL feature working, we need to enable it on the server-side and apply the service behavior in the service section(the endpoint should be within the `service` section instead of  `client` section).

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService3.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="sb">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService3.IService1"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="sb">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: I have svc less service which is hosted in another server, I have created the new service as wrapper and consuming the service as client. I updated the ques with main service config setting.

Comment: Try to remove the name of the service behavior.
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
Besides, As you publish services using the ServiceActivation section, note your service address.
http://example.com/TestService.svc?wsdl

Comment: that I have removed, but not working the http wsdl. problem is in between https and http

Comment: Why did you navigate Service.svc instead of TestService.svc in the browser?

Comment: that is example, i didn't change the url, sorry for miss match, just to update.. when I am using end user system then wsdl is automatically including the https in URL but same in local machine then it is not adding the https

Comment: how did you host the service? IIS ssl settings may disable http. Check the SSL settings.

Comment: Using IIS Binding

Comment: Uncheck the SSL required, besides Chrome now disable http protocol by default, try another browser